# C: Only a single array within a struct, why and when?

Tags: c, struct

What is the main benefit of putting a single array inside a struct? When would you do it? As an example:

```
struct Database{
  struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};
```

Now to create a database:

```
struct Database* db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
```

However it could be done like this too:

```
struct Address* db = malloc(sizeof(struct Address) * MAX_ROWS);
```

I think one reason is better documentation/understanding from code (code self explanation), for example the signature `foo(struct Database*)` seems much better than `foo(struct Address*)`, but is there another important reason too? Is there a general rule for when you would wrap an array within a struct?

Comment: you'll be able to `return` it from a function for instance. Well, that's underperformant, that said